# how to update xml file from another xml file dynamically?

Tags: java, android, xml, updatexml

I would like to update an xml file from another xml file.I have used an xml file as shown below:

**one.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#00BFFF">   
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:visibility="visible">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:visibility="visible">

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**two.xml** as follows:

```
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
       <map>
      <int name="linearLayout1" value="8" />
      <int name="linearLayout2" value="0" />
      </map>
```

from the above two xml files i would like to change the attribute value one. xml when 
if

```
  <int name ="linearLayout1" value = "8"/>
```

from **two.xml** then I would like to update **one.xml** file as where LinearLayout **android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"** then change the attribute value as **android:visibility="gone"**.

Comment: "change the attribute value one. xml when if **from **two.xml", explain about more.

Comment: i would like to get updated one.xml file

Comment: what is your platform if it's windows use "\\" to read files

Comment: what happen, it's not the code what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code what you want it's

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse("/home/riddhish/developerworkspace/SplitString/src/com/updatexmlwithjava/two.xml");           
    DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) doc;
    Node a = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(a, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);
```

/**
    *  Logic for checking 
    **/

```
boolean flag=false;
for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
       Element e = (Element) n;                
            if ("int".equals(e.getTagName())) {
                if(e.getAttribute("name").equals("linearLayout1")){
                        if(e.getAttribute("value").equals("8"))
                            flag=true;                      
                    }                    
            } 
}
```

/**
* Logic for reading one.xml and setting android:visibility="gone"
**/

```
docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = docBuilder.parse("/home/riddhish/developerworkspace/SplitString/src/com/updatexmlwithjava/one.xml");           
traversal = (DocumentTraversal) doc;
a = doc.getDocumentElement();
iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(a, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);            
for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
      Element e = (Element) n;                
          if ("LinearLayout".equals(e.getTagName())) {
                if(e.getAttribute("android:id").equals("@+id/linearLayout1")){
                        if(flag==true){
                            System.out.println(""+e.getAttribute("android:visibility"));
                            e.setAttribute("android:visibility", "gone");
                        }                           
                }                    
          } 
}
```

/**
* Logic for rewriting one.xml 
**/

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/home/riddhish/developerworkspace/SplitString/src/com/updatexmlwithjava/one.xml"));
iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(a, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);          
doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ScrollView");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);
for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {               
        rootElement.appendChild(doc.importNode(n, true));
}
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer,But it is applicable for only linearLayout1.If some one modify the two.xml then what how should we write dynamically.

Comment: you have getAttribute(),getTagName(),getTextContent() to check dynamically values of attributes ,so it's depends on your logic how you want to set.