# XML data as an accessible object

Tags: java, android, xml

Please, need your help.

I want to use an XML structure as an object, or just like an object of a class.

XML myObj = read it from file.

then

```
XmlNode node = myObj.SelectNode(NAME);

if (node != null) node.InnerText = "My text and my value";
```

I want to work with XML because will send it to pipe without serialization to C# machine. Where it will be deserialized from the XML.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: I would look at JSON format for this

Comment: For XML, look at [DocumentBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) class. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21538403/808940)

Comment: yes, it's called DOM bTree structure.. you'd add this as the answer also.