# Java XML importNode function not working as expected

Tags: java, xml, dom, import, xml-parsing

My XML looks like [this.](http://pastebin.com/fPhSRKrV)

I would like to "export" collected_objects into another document. Here is my code-

```
  NodeList nList = reader.getElementsByTagName("collected_objects");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                output.importNode(nNode, true);

            }
```

output refers to the new document I want to write to.

The code is not [importing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29) anything from source document. All I get is XML "header" - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`

I was expecting that since I've set `deep` to true, all of the child nodes will be imported but that is not happening.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`importNode` only imports the node to the document. You still have to append it somewhere using `Node.appendNode(child)`

Answer (score 3):

**use importNode using this way**

```
Element rootElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("collected_objects");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);
for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {               
        rootElement.appendChild(doc.importNode(n, true));
}
```

Comment: see example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884051/how-to-update-xml-file-from-another-xml-file-dynamically/9884503#9884503