# How to populate a SQLite database with data from a xml file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I am writing a Android app in Java, I need to populate a SQLite database with data from a xml file, what code can I use to do this?
The XML file will be a Microsoft access Database that has been exported to a XML file, the data in the file needs to be saved in a SQLite database.

I am developing in Eclipse with the Android SDK.

Answer (score 3):

You can do with this way

1. [You have parse your XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884051/how-to-update-xml-file-from-another-xml-file-dynamically/9884503#9884503)
2. [Than insert into databse](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InsertRecordsUsingPreparedStatement.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Add your xml file in assets folder and then parse it by using this..! XmlContentHandler is an handler class which implements DefaultHandler.

```
        InputStream inputStream;
        try 
        {

            inputStream = getAssets().open("persons.xml");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream); 

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

            XmlContentHandler handler =  new XmlContentHandler();

            xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
            xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(inputStreamReader));

            ArrayList<Person> array = handler.getArray();
            ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.list_item, array);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your XML file using a "parser". You should check for JSOUP, XPATH, etc... There are many!

Regards.